# Add dynamic columns to table after appending word to column name and checking for existing column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am using SQl-server, and have been working on this for a while for work but running into a lot of issues.

I started with a table “Logs”

```
| ChangeID | UserID | LogDate | Status   | Fields
| 123      | 001    | 7-12-12 | Open     | (raw data)
| 456      | 001    | 7-9-14  | Complete | (raw data)
| 789      | 002    | 5-8-15  | Open     | (raw data)
```

The column “Fields” contains data from a form in JSON format. Basically, it contains a field name, a before value and an after value. 
For every row in Fields, I am able to parse the JSON in order to get a temporary table #fieldTable. So for example, one row of raw data in the Fields column would produce the following table:

```
|Field      |Before |After
|User       |ZZZ    |YYY
|requestDue |7-2-13 |7-5-14
|Assigned   |No     |Yes
```

There can be any number of values for Field, and the names of the fields are not known beforehand.
What I need is for there to be a final table which combines all of the temporary tables generated with the field values as new columns, like this:

```
| ChangeID | UserID | LogDate | Status | Fields | UserBefore | UserAfter | requestDueBefore | requestDueAfter | … |
```

where, if the same field name appeared in two different rows of the JSON (and consequently the table that formats the data from it), then a new column won’t be added but rather just the data will be updated. So, for example, if the row with ChangeID 123 had the raw data

```
[{“field":"reqId", “before”: “000”,"after":"111"},{"field":"affected",”before”:no,"after":"yes"},{"field":"application",”before”:xxx,"after":"yyy"}]
```

and the ChangeID 789 had the raw data in its Fields row as

```
[{“field":"attachments", “before”: “null”,"after":"zzzzzzz"},{"field":"affected",”before”:no,"after":"yes}]
```

, then because the field “affected” from ChangeID123 should result in columns affectedBefore and affectedAfter to the final table, when this field is seen again from Change789, new columns won’t be added.

If there is no data for some column of a particular row, it should just be null.

The way I thought to do this was to first try to dynamically pivot the temporary tables when they are generated so that I get the following result for the before results

```
|User   |requestDue |Assigned
|ZZZ    |7-2-13     |No
```

and another for the after results

```
|User   |requestDue |Assigned
|YYY    |7-5-14     |Yes
```

by using the following code:

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max),
    @query  as nvarchar(max)
select @cols = stuff((select ',' + QUOTENAME(field) 
                    from #fieldTable
                    group by field--, id
                    --order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select before, field 
                from #fieldTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(before)
                for field in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

(and then the same thing again with different variables for the result with the after values)

I think that there may be some way to dynamically concatenate the dynamic column name with a “before” or “after”, and then to somehow add these columns to a final table outside of the scope of the procedure. However, I’m not sure how, and I’m also not sure if this is even the best approach to the problem. I tried to use aliases, but I think you need to know the column name to make that work, and the same goes for altering a table to add more columns.

Also, I have seen that for many sort of similar issues, people were advised to user openrowset, which I am unable to use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer belongs better in a comment as it doesn't directly address your question - however, I don't have reputation yet to directly comment.

For what you are describing, you might consider a SQLXML data field. SQLXML allows you to store documents of arbitrary schema and SQL-Server natively supports queries against it.

It would allow to avoid what I think you are already finding to be considerable complexity with trying to dynamically create schemas based on models that are not foreknown.

Hope that helps.